# Creating File Object from XSSFWorkbook Object

Tags: file, xls

I have `XSSFWorkbook` object which I want to save to a particular location (using Amazon S3). For saving I am using some API which takes File object parameter.

I know that `XSSFWorkbook` exposes write method to write to a path. Is there any way I can get file object from `XSSFWorkbook`.